# For loop error: Uncaught ReferenceError, variable is not defined. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, uncaught-exception

I've created a css menu, and I want to make each one of them to change their color on mouseover event (I'm just learning javascript, and specially the for loop, I know  can achieve this with CSS3).

So, It's not working, I get this error on the DOM console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: linkIdOn is not defined (line 44)`

This is my CSS:

```
<body>
<div id="menuPrincipal">
<div id="link1" class="link"><a href="">Link 1</a></div>
<div id="link2" class="link"><a href="">Link 2</a></div>
<div id="link3" class="link"><a href="">Link 3</a></div>
<div id="link4" class="link"><a href="">Link 4</a></div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
    function cambioColorOnMouseover(){
    for (linkId=1; linkId<5; linkId++){
        var linkIdOn='link'+linkId;
        document.getElementById(linkIdOn).style.backgroundColor="#eee";
        console.log(linkIdOn);
    }
}
function cambioColorOnLeave(){
    for (linkId=1; linkId<5; linkId++){
        var linkIdOff='link'+linkId;
        document.getElementById(linkIdOff).style.backgroundColor="#ccc";
        console.log(linkIdOff);
    }
}
document.getElementById('link'+linkIdOn).onmouseover=cambioColorOnMouseover;  <-- line 44
document.getElementById('link'+linkIdOff).onmouseout=cambioColorOnLeave;
```

Comment: It's only defined inside the function, it's an issue with scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linkIdOn`'s scope is limited to `cambioColorOnMouseover`. But that is not your only problem. You need to move several things around.

My suggestion:

```
for(var linkId = 1; linkId < 5; linkId++) {
    document.getElementById('link'+linkId).onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
        console.log(this.id);
    };
    document.getElementById('link'+linkId).onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
        console.log(this.id);
    };
}
```

For the benefit of others who don't know the CSS3 way to do this (which, though the OP wants to do this in JavaScript, is the preferred way):

```
#link1, #link2, #link3, #link4, #link5 {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#link1:hover, #link2:hover, #link3:hover, #link4:hover, #link5:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Though if you did the CSS, you would likely have a `link` class instead of using ids.

(I´ve changed two small typos that prevented the example to work (the system tells me that edits must be at least 6 characters) Thanks for your help! - Rosamunda)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like:

```
function linkOn() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
}

function linkOff() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
}

window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.links;
  for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    links[i].onmouseover = linkOn;
    links[i].onmouseout = linkOff;
  }
}
```

though you are likely better off to add and remove a class so you can control the effect through CSS rather than script.